# undefined method `find_in_source_paths'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5473e390d362755125d2f47b64ef0a135f2fe111/railties/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb#L55

I have tried locating this method in rails, but I think it's available somewhere else.
I am trying to generate a migration from my local gem.
So what I am doing:

```
migration_template source_file, destination_file
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same issue and neither of the provided answers fixes it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `include Thor::Actions` to my class containing `migration_template` fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I believe find_in_source_paths(file) is in [Thor](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/Thor%2FActions%3Afind_in_source_paths) library under action. I don't see you have included thor gem in your gemfile. Please try that.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like:

```
require 'rails/test_help'

class SomeClass
 include Rails::Generators::Migration
end

SomeClass.new.migration_template(....)
```

Referrences: [LINK1](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/issues/164), [LINK2](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Generators/Migration/migration_template)